# Gentoo machine on new network don't get an ip address from the DHCP server

Tags: linux, networking, gentoo, dynamic-ip

I just moved my stationery/server from one town to an other and 
now the Internet connection have stopped working.

It is the same Internet supplier in both towns 
it is called Waoo Fiberbredbånd.

The server is running Gentoo Linux and the problem is 
that it don't get an ip address from the DHCP server.

```
dhcpcd[24485]: version 6.4.7 starting
dhcpcd[24485]: dev: loaded udev
dhcpcd[24485]: no interfaces have a carrier
dhcpcd[24485]: forked to background, child pid 24506
```

I tried different things and discovered that if I boot a Ubuntu LiveUSB
on the server it gets assigned a ip address just fine.

Then I assumed that my system was to old, so I tried to boot from a
new Gentoo LiveUSB, but I got the same error.

Here is some ifconfig information from the Gentoo LiveUSB.

```
eth0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        ether 00:19:66:79:69:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 45  base 0x6000  

lo: flags=73  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And the route information from the Gentoo LiveUSB

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
loopback        localhost       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
```

The ifconfig information from the Ubuntu LiveUSB

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:66:79:69:d0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.135  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::219:66ff:fe79:69d0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3307 (3.3 KB)  TX bytes:8301 (8.3 KB)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3312 (3.3 KB)  TX bytes:3312 (3.3 KB)
```

And the route information from the working Ubuntu LiveUSB.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

So how come it is working on Ubuntu but not on Gentoo? 
And what are the strange 'flags=' writing in the GentooUSB ifconfig output?

Comment: Do you have a DHCP client running ? If not, then you won't get an ip address from the DHCP server.

Comment: Yes the DHCP fail to get an ip address. But good point, I miss it in my question.

Comment: updated with the information.

Comment: try another DHCP client...Ubuntu uses `dhclient` instead of `dhcpcd`. Maybe it solves the problem.

Comment: Tried to switch DHCP client, did not help. I think the problem is in the kernel.

Comment: If you still have this problem - can you post output of `lspci -k`